# Bubble sorting in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I've been trying to code to sort the words in alphabetical order, but been bumping into a few problems. 
Here's my main .cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int Sort (char [] [20], int, int);

void main ()
{
char Strings [10] [20]
                = { "One",
                    "Two",
                    "Three",
                    "Four",
                    "Five",
                    "Six",
                    "Seven",
                    "Eight",
                    "Nine",
                    "Ten"   };
int i;
cout << "Unsorted Strings are" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << '\t' << Strings [i] << endl;
Sort (Strings, 10, 20);
cout << "Sorted Strings are" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << '\t' << Strings [i] << endl;
}
```

Here's my code so far.

```
.386
public  _Sort
.model flat
.code
.data

_Sort       proc
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    esi
        push    edi
        mov     ecx, [ebp + 16]     
        add     ecx, 3
        sar     ecx, 2
        sal     ecx, 2
        sub     esp, ecx    
        mov     edx, esp    

        mov     edi, [ebp + 8]  
        mov     esi, edi

        L1:
        push    ecx
        mov     esi, [ebp +8]

        L2:
        mov     al, [esi]
        cmp     [esi + 20], al
        jg      L3
        mov     eax, [esi]
        xchg    eax, [esi +20]
        mov     [esi], eax

        L3:
        add     esi, 20
        loop    L2
        pop     ecx
        loop    L1

        L4:
        pop     edi
        pop     esi
        pop     ebp
        ret
_Sort       endp

    end
```

I'm trying to follow the instructions in the book, but it's a little different from the program I have to write. Anyone willing to clarify on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What problems are you bumping into? Have you tried debugging the code?

Comment: Write a bubble sort in C first.

Comment: I don't see any loops in your assembly code, you cannot have a sorting algorithm without loops...

Answer (score 0):

Well, until now, you goes pretty well. The stack frame code in `Sort` is ready and seems to be OK. Also the parameter passing is ready.

Now you have to write the bubble sort itself, between the lines `mov     esi, edi` and `pop     edi`.

Comment: Just edited my original post with some added code. My program doesn't run, gives me an error of "use of register assumed to ERROR." Is it because I wrote some bad code somewhere?

Comment: Well, I can't help you with MASM error messages. Just read the manual. Also, one suggestion - why not trying to first sort an array full of numbers. Sorting strings actually include two algorithms - sorting itself and comparing strings what is another algorithm and probably have to be implemented as a separate procedure.

Comment: Another suggestion - try to organize the loops without using `loop` instruction. This will allow you to use two separate registers as a counters and not push/pop ecx all the time.